# Why am I obtaining this error response trying to execute a simple GET all to a REST API using Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am working on a Spring Boot project and I am finding some difficulties trying to perform a simple GET API call using Spring Template (it works without problem for other APIs call into my project).

Basically I have this method:

```
private NotaryDistrict fetchNotaryDistrictDetailsFromAPI() throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
    System.out.println("fetchNotaryDistrictDetails() START !!!");
    LOGGER.debug("Notary deiscrit details URL: {}", notaryDistrictDetailsURL);
            
    ResponseEntity<NotaryDistrict> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://MAYPI.SERVICE.it/ws-application/service/distretti/CG7drXn9fvA%253D", NotaryDistrict.class);
    NotaryDistrict notaryDistrictDetails = response.getBody();
    
    System.out.println("notaryDistric details: " + notaryDistrictDetails);

    return notaryDistrictDetails;
}
```

At the moment I directly mocked the API URL as parameter of the **getForEntity()** method. As you can see the API endpoint URL end with a query parameter representing the ID of the object that I want to retrieve (in this specific case **CG7drXn9fvA%253D**).

The problem is that when perform this line:

```
ResponseEntity<NotaryDistrict> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://MAYPI.SERVICE.it/ws-application/service/distretti/CG7drXn9fvA%253D", NotaryDistrict.class);
```

it throw this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{"errors":["Parametro IdDistrict non valido."]}]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:361) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.SecondStepItemProcessor.fetchNotaryDistrictDetailsFromAPI(SecondStepItemProcessor.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.SecondStepItemProcessor.process(SecondStepItemProcessor.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.SecondStepItemProcessor.process(SecondStepItemProcessor.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:413) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy61.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.runSpringBatchExampleJob(SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

This error section is in italian:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{"errors":["Parametro IdDistrict non valido."]}]
```

the error meaning is: "IdDistrict parameter is not valid".

The strange thing is that performing the same API call (the same endpoint) via cURL or via PostMan it woks fine, as you can see here:

[image]

It seems that the problem is related to the  ID of the object that I want to retrieve: **CG7drXn9fvA%253D** because in Postman I obtain the same error if i put an invalid ID:

[image]

I suspect that maybe the problem could be related to the fact that this ID contains the "%" character.

What can I try to do to solve this problem and obtain the expected output from my call?

Comment: Try to call to this URL `https://maypi.service.it/ws-application/service/distretti/CG7drXn9fvA=`

Comment: @4EACH I tried with this ID into Postman and it retrieve the correct element. Why have you changed "CG7drXn9fvA%253D" with "CG7drXn9fvA="? What is the logic? and in case how to automatically convert?

Comment: `%253D` is the encoded chars of `=`. It seems the encoding applied twice and then the id was wrong. make sure id in URL is decoded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform the API call by providing problematic identifier (since it might contain special charaters like '%' which are used for URL encoding) as a third parameter to `getForEntity` method call. This way the endpoint URL should be properly encoded. Therefore, the following should help:

```java
ResponseEntity<NotaryDistrict> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "https://MAYPI.SERVICE.it/ws-application/service/distretti/{id}",
                NotaryDistrict.class, "CG7drXn9fvA%253D");
```

Comment: I am still obtaining the same error message :-(

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself performing the call in this way:

```
String url3 = "https://MYAPY.XXX.it/ws-application/service/distretti/{id}";
url3 = url3.replace("{id}", "CG7drXn9fvA%253D");
URI uri = new URI(url3);
System.out.println(uri);

ResponseEntity<String> forEntity2 = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);

System.out.println(forEntity2.getStatusCodeValue());
System.out.println(forEntity2.getBody());
```

Comment: Try to call to this URL `https://maypi.service.it/ws-application/service/distretti/CG7drXn9fvA=`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure id in URL decoded:

`%253D` is the encoded chars of `=`. It seems the encoding applied twice and then the id was wrong. make sure id in URL is decoded

```
private NotaryDistrict fetchNotaryDistrictDetailsFromAPI() throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
    System.out.println("fetchNotaryDistrictDetails() START !!!");
    LOGGER.debug("Notary deiscrit details URL: {}", notaryDistrictDetailsURL);
            
    ResponseEntity<NotaryDistrict> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://MAYPI.SERVICE.it/ws-application/service/distretti/CG7drXn9fvA=", NotaryDistrict.class);
    NotaryDistrict notaryDistrictDetails = response.getBody();
    
    System.out.println("notaryDistric details: " + notaryDistrictDetails);

    return notaryDistrictDetails;
}
```